# Retrieving value from two arrays

Tags: javascript, json

I have two arrays.

- STUD = `[{"id":1,"name":"Kida"},{"id":2,"name":"Kidb"},{"id":3,"name":"Kidc"},{"id":4,"name":"Kidd"},{"id":5,"name":"Kide"}]`
- IDCRD = `[{"id":3,"status":"Y"},{"id":4,"status":"Y"},{"id":2,"status":"N"},{"id":5,"status":"Y"},{"id":1,"status":"N"}]`

Then I have a loop:

```
for(var i=0;i<STUD.length;i++){
    var id = STUD[i][0];
    var name = STUD[i][1];
    var status = ? 
}
```

I need the status for `STUD[i]` from `IDCRD` array having the same ID inside this loop.

Comment: there;s no JSON in the code you posted - so it's much simpler than you thought

Comment: what you expecting output data

Comment: status = "N" for STUD[0],

Comment: @XiOXiS check now.

Answer (score 0):

Have another loop on IDCRD  and match ids of STUD and IDCRD then get the status

```js
STUD = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Kida"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Kidb"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Kidc"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Kidd"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "name": "Kide"
}];
IDCRD = [{
  "id": 3,
  "status": "Y"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "status": "Y"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "status": "N"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "status": "Y"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "status": "N"
}];
  for (var i = 0; i < STUD.length; i++) {
    var id = STUD[i].id;
    var name = STUD[i].name;
    for (j = 0; j < IDCRD.length; j++) {
      if (STUD[i].id == IDCRD[j].id) {
        var status = IDCRD[j].status;
      }
    }
    console.log(id, name, status);
  }
```

Comment: This is not expected output:

Comment: 1 Kida N, 2 Kidb N, 3 Kidc Y, 4 Kidd Y, 5 Kide Y

Answer (score 0):

The function `status` should do what you need

```js
var STUD = [{"id":1,"name":"Kida"},{"id":2,"name":"Kidb"},{"id":3,"name":"Kidc"},{"id":4,"name":"Kidd"},{"id":5,"name":"Kide"}];
var IDCRD = [{"id":3,"status":"Y"},{"id":4,"status":"Y"},{"id":2,"status":"N"},{"id":5,"status":"Y"},{"id":1,"status":"N"}];

function status(i){ return IDCRD.filter(w => w.id == STUD[i].id)[0].status }

console.log(status(0));
console.log(status(1));
console.log(status(2));
console.log(status(3));
console.log(status(4));
```

or if you run with Node you can write

`status = i => IDCRD.filter(w => w.id == STUD[i].id)[0].status`

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and use `id` as key and take the map for an easy access to the data of `IDCRD`.

```js
var stud = [{ id: 1, name: "Kida" }, { id: 2, name: "Kidb" }, { id: 3, name: "Kidc" }, { id: 4, name: "Kidd" }, { id: 5, name: "Kide" }],
    IDCRD = [{ id: 3, status: "Y" }, { id: 4, status: "Y" }, { id: 2, status: "N" }, { id: 5, status: "Y" }, { id: 1, status: "N" }],
    map = IDCRD.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.id, o), new Map),
    result = stud.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, map.get(o.id)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another solution could be using [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), but this approach iterates the array for each item to find.

```js
var stud = [{ id: 1, name: "Kida" }, { id: 2, name: "Kidb" }, { id: 3, name: "Kidc" }, { id: 4, name: "Kidd" }, { id: 5, name: "Kide" }],
    IDCRD = [{ id: 3, status: "Y" }, { id: 4, status: "Y" }, { id: 2, status: "N" }, { id: 5, status: "Y" }, { id: 1, status: "N" }],
    result = stud.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, IDCRD.find(({ id }) => id === o.id)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```